# How is Firebase's authentication UID generated?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

**My Question:** How is Firebase's Auth UID generated?

**Current Scenario:** I want to give each user (who registers on my website) a *good looking unique id*. *Examples:* a 6-digit number, a mix of digits and strings (like korean5684, indian8439) and I don't want any collisions.

So, I'm looking for a way to hash from Firebase's Auth UID to a custom ID with as few collisions as possible. For efficient hashing, I need to know the way the UID is generated.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm used for Firebase Authentication UIDs is undocumented, has changed over time, and is dependent on the provider(s) used. You should not base your implementation on any assumption/knowledge on how the UID is generated.